Geometry Proximity - Permanent vertex attribute value switch ("Permanent/Temporary proximity trail")
Objective:
Toggle/Trigger attribute value permanently/temporarily, even after controller object left the proximity area.
Examples:
Controller objects leaving fading trail in material color
Controller object proximity translating vertices permanently

Found solution here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCQjOau6eIA
This is the setup:


If anyone knew the solution for objects (not vertices), please share. (i.e. translating entire objects)
